# How to add Azure Service Tag access restriction using Bicep

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

Is there a way to add a "Service Tag" access restriction (e.g. AzureDevOps) to an Azure Function App via Bicep?  In the Bicep documentation for Sites I can only really see the "ipSecurityRestrictions" of siteConfig, I can't see anywhere how to add a service tag based restriction (as per below screenshot applied which was done direct in the portal)?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a property of `Microsoft.Web/sites/config`; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-web?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#ipsecurityrestriction

```
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "AzureDevOps",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "tag": "ServiceTag",
                        "priority": 100,
                        "name": "ADO"
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this before in the ipSecurityRestrictions section but I didn't add the "tag" attribute so thanks again!